# HttpWebRequest throws "The remote server returned an error: NotFound." on VS for Win Phone

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, windows-phone, httpwebresponse

I know other people posted the same issue, I read those posts but their solutions didn't work to me :(

I am creating a C# app on Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone.

The app needs to send a HTTP GET but doesn't seem to work.
To test it I cut out all the headers and everything else, and just kept the core code...but still throws me the same exception:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest;
webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestCallback), webRequest);
```

and

```
private void GetRequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

The debug stops inside of GetRequestCallback function throwing:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
Additional information: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

I also looked into the manifest, and these are the capabilities:

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_GAMERSERVICES"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MICROPHONE"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_CONTACTS"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_APPOINTMENTS"/>
</Capabilities>
```

Also, I have been trying with and without Fiddler open but nothing changes.
However, when it is open, I can't see any request sent from my machine. It's like if the app really doesn't even access the internet.

Any idea? What am I doing wrong? Should I setup something more on my pc to develop an app that can access the internet, or maybe use a different version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Google probably wants a User-Agent.  Also, Google is SSL-only.

Comment: A `GET` request to `http://www.google.com` with no headers in Fiddler returns a `200 OK`.  Maybe it's a problem with the emulator using your PCs network connection?  Does the browser in the emulator work?

Comment: yea the browser on the emulator works...

I think I can't even make Fiddler work with it tho, cause I tried now a sample app and Fiddler doesn't track the messages from that app either -.-

I'm starting to think that maybe the problem is in the BeginGetResponse, maybe I wrote something wrong in its arguments.

Comment: I can't provide any help with that, but I recently watched a [Windows Phone 8 video series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners) on Channel 9, and in [part 26](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-26-Retrieving-a-Photo-from-Flickrs-API) he uses `HttpClient` to make a request to the FlickrAPI.  Maybe you can try using `HttpClient` instead.  Search down in the episode notes on that page for "HttpClient" to quickly see what the code looks like.  Good luck!

Comment: aghh, no okay, it's not an error in the code, it's just an annoying problem -.-''
at some point even the sample app that I tried earlier (and was working) didn't work anymore and started throwing the same error. I restarted the pc and now, without opening Fiddler even once, everything works.. the sample app I downloaded, and now also my code.

Thanks adrift though! I'll check out that link now. I am just starting with C# and need to learn a lot. I thought it was more similar to other languages I know...but it's not quite like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a same problem, i solved the problem just i reconnected my internet connection in my emulator, or you can use device . .